# How to check when last git pull command was performed?

Tags: repository, git-pull

How do I check the last date time of git pull request made, as I have done some changes in my repo and trying to push them but before it I used "git pull" but it says "Already uptodate", now I use "git push" but unable to push changes as it says "Everything up-to-date". While git status shows modified files in staged and unstaged.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While `git status` shows modified files in staged and unstaged.

You need to commit the staged files first, in order to be able to push

```
cd /path/to/repo
git commit -m "Add files"
git push
```